# Conformal map from $\{0<Re(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ to $\{0<Im(z)<\pi\}$

Tags: conformal-geometry

Could anyone help me to think about a conformal map from $\{0<Re(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ to $\{0<Im(z)<\pi\}$? 
And how could we approach the question about finding a conformal mapping? I know that $z^2$ doubles the angle, but are there any other conformal mapping widely used?

Thank you!

Comment: If you draw the two sets it is immediately clear how you have to proceed:
First Rotate the first set by $\pi/2$ (counter-clockwise), then dilate it by a factor $2$. Can you express these operations mathematically, via maps? Are these operation conformal?

Comment: How I learned to deal with this kind of problems is via looking at examples and by experimenting with the various conformal transformations: for example, look at $z\mapsto kz,z+k,e^{ki}z,\overline{z},\frac{1}{z},z^k$ for various values of $k$ and never forget the most important map (whose name I don't remember) $\mathbb{H}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}\quad z\mapsto  \frac{z-i}{z+i}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say $f: z \mapsto 2iz$. The reason behind that is that the multiplication by $2$ will have the effect of transforming $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ into $(0,\pi)$, and will transform $Re(z)$ into $Im(z)$.

Proof: if $Re(z) \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we can write: $z=a+ib$ with $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Then $f(z)=2iz = -2b+2ia$, therefore $Im(f(z)) = 2a \in (0,\pi)$. It is obvious that $f$ is bijective.

It is obvious that $f$ is conform because it is the composite of an homothety (multiplication by $2$) and a rotation (multiplication by $i$), so the angle between two vectors is the same angle between their images.

Comment: Yes, but you commented after that I began to write this answer and before I finished to do so, so I didn't have the time to see your comment. Sorry for the double answer then.

Comment: Thank you both! And is $2\bar z$ also correct?

Comment: No: $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ takes the upper half plane and sends it to the lower half plane, so in particular leaves your initial set fix.
@R.Bourgeon, not a problem. Yours is just the expanded version of mine

Comment: @b00nheT Oh yes thank you. Could you give some general procedures on questions like finding conformal map? Cause I first try to split the question into finding $arg(w)$ in terms of $arg(z)$ and $|w|$ in terms of |z| but I don't know how to relate w and z in this question.

Comment: @J.Y I suppose that what you call $w$ here is the image of $z$. So, as I told you, we take: $w=2iz$. Can you express $arg(w)$ and $\vert w \vert$ from $z$ ?

Comment: @J.Y Also $z \mapsto 2i\bar z$ is not conformal; it reverses the orientation of angles at the infinitesimal level.

Comment: Yes I understand now. Thank you so much.